# Same hyperref options for both digital copy and hard copy?

Tags: hyperref

I'm looking for a "good" set of options for hyperpdf that will result in a neatly looking PDF, suitable for both print and digital viewing.

If I simply use `\usepackage{hyperref}`, I get a red box around every TOC entry and a green box around every reference, which is not presentable.

Comment: Or a simple switch; e.g.: `\newif\ifcolour \colourtrue \ifcolour \hypersetup{colorlinks, allcolors=blue} \else \hypersetup{hidelinks} \fi`. Then just comment out `\colourtrue` when you want to print.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is the set of options that were used for the `hyperref` [manual](https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/hyperref-doc.zip) itself:

```
  \usepackage[%
    pdftex,%
    colorlinks,%
    hyperindex,%
    plainpages=false,%
    bookmarksopen,%
    bookmarksnumbered,
    pdfusetitle,%
  ]{hyperref}
```

This way all the boxed will be gone, and the TOC items text color will become red, and the refs text color will become green.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from my [PHD thesis](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/latex-thesis-template-manuel-kuehner/) as a starting point:

```
\usepackage[%
bookmarks, 
bookmarksopen=true, 
bookmarksopenlevel=1, 
bookmarksnumbered=true, 
hidelinks,
pdfstartpage={1}, 
pdfstartview={FitH},
pdfpagelabels=true,
plainpages=false,
hyperfootnotes=true,
]{hyperref}
```

I think `hidelinks` is the most important part (removing color and border).